# How do I cause my computer to use lot of RAM?

Tags: bash

I am looking for a command(s) that could cause my Linux computer to use lot of RAM ?
Any pointers?

I want to run that in the back ground and do some other task that needs already high RAM usage.

Thanks!

Comment: Write a C program, call malloc(one MILLION megabytes).

Comment: I need to do this in bash ..sorry.

Comment: @Travis  Dr. Evil -- is that you?

Comment: Fork Bomb : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb

Comment: Already tried fork bomb, does not work for me. That too strong. Makes my computer unresponsive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That one will cause growing memory usage by bash:

```
while read f; do arr[$((i++))]=$f; done < /dev/urandom
```

Another hard way might be (be careful):

```
while read f; do arr="$arr:$arr:$arr:$arr:$f"; done < /dev/urandom
```

Softer version:

```
while read f; do arr="$arr:$f"; done < /dev/urandom
```

to reclaim parts of the memory call:

```
unset arr
```

You could also mix it with a fork bomb... but I would avoid it

Comment: @abc: Are you sure the shell is Bash?

Comment: The shell is sh , linked to busybox.

Answer (score 2):

The current answer will try to use more RAM until it's simply completely out of RAM. For a more controlled approach, if you have basic GNU tools (`head` and `tail`) or BusyBox on Linux, you can do this to **fill a certain amount of free memory**:

```
</dev/zero head -c BYTES | tail
</dev/zero head -c 5000m | tail #~5GB, portable
</dev/zero head -c 5G    | tail #5GiB on GNU (not busybox)
cat /dev/zero | head -c 5G | tail #Easier notation; does the same thing
```

This works because tail needs to keep the current line in memory, in case it turns out to be the last line. The line, read from `/dev/zero` which outputs only null bytes and no newlines, will be infinitely long, but is limited by `head` to `BYTES` bytes, thus `tail` will use only that much memory. For a more precise amount, you will need to check how much RAM `head` and `tail` itself use on your system and subtract that.

To just quickly **run out of RAM completely**, you can remove the limiting `head` part:

```
tail /dev/zero
```

If you want to also **add a duration**, this can be done quite easily in `bash` (will not work in `sh`):

```
cat <( </dev/zero head -c 500m) <(sleep SECONDS) | tail
```

The `<(command)` thing seems to be little known but is often extremely useful, more info on it here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

The `cat` command will wait for inputs to complete until exiting, and by keeping one of the pipes open, it will keep `tail` alive.

If you have `pv` and want to **slowly increase RAM use**:

```
</dev/zero head -c TOTAL | pv -L BYTES_PER_SEC | tail
</dev/zero head -c 1000m | pv -L 10m | tail
```

The latter will use up to one gigabyte at a rate of ten megabytes per second. As an added bonus, `pv` will **show the current rate of use and the total use so far**. Of course this can also be done with previous variants:

```
</dev/zero head -c 500m | pv | tail
```

Just inserting the `| pv |` part will show you the current status (throughput and total by default).

If you do not have a `/dev/zero` device, the standard `yes` and `tr` tools might substitute: `yes | tr \\n x | head -c BYTES | tail` (`yes` outputs an infinite amount of "yes"es, `tr` substitutes the newline such that everything becomes one huge line and tail needs to keep all that in memory).
Another, simpler alternative is using `dd`: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1G of=/dev/null` uses 1GB of memory on GNU and BusyBox, but also 100% CPU on one core.
Finally, if your `head` does not accept a suffix, you can calculate an amount of bytes inline, for example 50 megabytes: `head -c $((1024*1024*50))`

---

<sub>Cross-posted from [my answer on the Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254976/30731)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit -m` can be used to impose an artificial memory limit on a process.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a command / logic that could cause computer to use lot of RAM. It would be difficult to use ulimit with my task.

Answer (score 0):

Use this at your own risk :

> :(){ :|:& };:

=> Explosion in your ram

Comment: that one will rather take processor power not the ram itself ... but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Anyway , this is not what "abc" need :/

Comment: Yes, this won't solve the purpose. I am on embedded linux so fork bomb completely hoses the cpu and I can't do anything. Plus the shell does not have arrays implemented.